# A procedure that receives a letter and a number that shows for example : (A,3) A AA AAA

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Make a procedure called paintletter, it receives two parameters,
a letter and a number. it will have to paint on the screen lines with the specified letters starting with a letter and ending with as many letters as the parameter says (USE BUCLES).

###### My exercise works but can it be improved in any way?

```
USE almacen;
 
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS paintletter$$
CREATE PROCEDURE paintletter(IN letter CHAR(1),IN num INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE AUX INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE LETR VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "";
    WHILE (num > AUX) DO
        SELECT CONCAT(LETR,letter);
        SET LETR = concat(LETR,letter);
        SET AUX = AUX + 1;
    END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

### For example : paintletter("B",4)

```
B 

BB 

BBB 

BBBB
```

**here is a link to how it works :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/97

Comment: See also the `REPEAT()` function.